# Excel - colour coding and formulae

Tags: excel

In an Excel spreadsheet, with columns containing strings A1, F1 etc. for example:

A1,         B1,         E1,         C1,         D1,         F1
A1,         B1,         E1,         C1,         D1,         F2
A1,         B1,         E2,         C1,         D1,         F1

[1] Would like to create a column that says "Yes" for cells with equal numbers of strings that end with 1 and 2?

For e.g. rows which contain
A1 B1 E1 C2 D2 F2,
or

A2 B1 E1 C2 D1 F2

would be flagged as "Yes"

[2] Colour code the rows that have a "Yes" in [1]?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in ColumnsA:F, please select ColumnA:F and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$F1,"*"&1)=COUNTIF($A1:$F1,"*"&2)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

For the `Yes` you can use the same formula inside IF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:$F1,"*"&1)=COUNTIF($A1:$F1,"*"&2),"Yes")
```

(Won't work with a mix of `1` and `2` in the same cell.)

Answer (score 0):

Sub like this would do the job but change the NumberOfRows appropriately. (You did not ask to stop at the empty row).

```
Sub ChangeColor()
NumberOfRows = 4
For j = 1 To NumberOfRows
   Yes = 0
   For i = 1 To 6
      If Right((Cells(j, i).Value), 1) = "1" Then
          Yes = Yes + 1
          Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
      End If
   Next i
   If (Yes = 3) Then
      Cells(j, 7).Value = "Yes"
      Rows(j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
   End If
Next j
```

End Sub